# First responder error: non-key window attempting reload - allowing due to manual keyboard. UITextEffectsWindow should not become key

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, wkwebview

I have a textView and above it I have a separate view that has an inline WKWebView inside of it.

```
view.addSubView(textField)
view.addSubView(separateView)
separateView.addSubview(wkWebView)
```

If I start panning and pinching around the wkWebView enough I get errors. The main 2 things that stand out are

**First responder error: non-key window attempting reload - allowing due to manual keyboard (first responder window is <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow...**

and

**UITextEffectsWindow should not become key. Please file a bug to Keyboard**

It seems that I can't safely add the wkWebView inside of the separate view because this crash keeps happening. Once it occurs the entire app becomes unusable.

> [View] First responder error: non-key window attempting reload -
> allowing due to manual keyboard (first responder window is
>
> <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x1080c1c00; frame = (0 0; 414 896); opaque =
> NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x2838eefc0>>, key
> window is <UIWindow: 0x107111e70; frame = (0 0; 414 896);
> gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28364dad0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer:
> 0x28381ef60>>)
>
> [View] First responder error: non-key window attempting reload -
> allowing due to manual keyboard (first responder window is
>
> <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x1080c1c00; frame = (0 0; 414 896); opaque =
> NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x2838eefc0>>, key
> window is <UIWindow: 0x107111e70; frame = (0 0; 414 896);
> gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28364dad0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer:
> 0x28381ef60>>)
>
> Assert] UITextEffectsWindow should not become key. Please file a bug to Keyboard | iOS with this call stack:
>
> (
>
> 0   UIKitCore 0x00000001a638b204 33B02AB5-5DAF-3249-8DC6-5872DF830EC5
>
> - 15569412
>
> 1   UIKitCore 0x00000001a60cee3c 33B02AB5-5DAF-3249-8DC6-5872DF830EC5
>
> - 12701244
>
> 2   WebKit 0x00000001b0157c5c 9F7B0B3B-7F33-3F7F-883E-7B2EE83F42FB +
> 7429212
>
> 3   WebKit 0x00000001afe510d4 9F7B0B3B-7F33-3F7F-883E-7B2EE83F42FB +
> 4255956
>
> 4   WebKit 0x00000001b00cac88 9F7B0B3B-7F33-3F7F-883E-7B2EE83F42FB +
> 6851720
>
> 5   WebKit 0x00000001afa93064 9F7B0B3B-7F33-3F7F-883E-7B2EE83F42FB +
> 331876
>
> 6   WebKit 0x00000001afe11538 9F7B0B3B-7F33-3F7F-883E-7B2EE83F42FB +
> 3994936
>
> 7   WebKit 0x00000001afa74858 9F7B0B3B-7F33-3F7F-883E-7B2EE83F42FB +
> 206936
>
> 8   WebKit 0x00000001afa7414c 9F7B0B3B-7F33-3F7F-883E-7B2EE83F42FB +
> 205132
>
> 9   JavaScriptCore 0x00000001ad9f4220
> 74545BAC-15FF-320D-A90B-8F89F75E39C1 + 16138784
>
> 10  JavaScriptCore 0x00000001ad9f51f0
> 74545BAC-15FF-320D-A90B-8F89F75E39C1 + 16142832
>
> 11  CoreFoundation 0x00000001a36089e8
> 4FBDF167-161A-324C-A233-D516922C67E5 + 670184
>
> 12  CoreFoundation 0x00000001a36088e4
> 4FBDF167-161A-324C-A233-D516922C67E5 + 669924
>
> 13  CoreFoundation 0x00000001a3607be8
> 4FBDF167-161A-324C-A233-D516922C67E5 + 666600
>
> 14  CoreFoundation 0x00000001a3601bc8
> 4FBDF167-161A-324C-A233-D516922C67E5 + 641992
>
> 15  CoreFoundation 0x00000001a3601360 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
>
> 16  GraphicsServices 0x00000001bac3f734 GSEventRunModal + 164
>
> 17  UIKitCore 0x00000001a607c584 33B02AB5-5DAF-3249-8DC6-5872DF830EC5
>
> - 12363140
>
> 18  UIKitCore 0x00000001a6081df4 UIApplicationMain + 168
>
> 19  libswiftUIKit.dylib 0x00000001b73c524c
> $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 104
>
> 20  myAppName 0x0000000104990800
> $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 120
>
> 21  myAppName 0x0000000104990778 $s7myAppName11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ
>
> - 48
>
> 22  myAppName 0x000000010499e3cc main + 32
>
> 23  libdyld.dylib 0x00000001a32bdcf8
> E574A365-9878-348A-8E84-91E163CFC128 + 7416
>
> )

Comment: do you use a Scene based app?

Comment: nah, regular. I've never used a Scene based before